# What pattern should I use to prevent overrun of asychronous calls that take too long

Tags: c#, asynchronous

My app needs to download price data from a webbased API every 200ms. I have to do some processing on that price data. If I run on a hypothetically slow processor and it cannot keep up I am wondering how to deal with it. Is there a common pattern around that I could use to deal with it?

For example. My sychronous c# code looks something like this;

```
Stopwatch Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
while (true) 
{
    Stopwatch.StartNew();

    await GetDataFromApiMethod();
    await ProcessDataFromApiMethod();

    Stopwatch.Stop();
    int Delay = 200 - (int)Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    if (Delay < 0) 
        Debug.WriteLine("Price Scheduler lag->" + Delay + "ms.");
    await Task.Delay(Delay);
}
```

The net effect of the above is that I just get lag. If it takes too long to process, well, I just don't get data every 200milliseconds.

Now if I made the above two awaited calls asynchronous. What happens when the processor can't keep up? ...and how would one deal with it? is there a common pattern for this sort of problem?

Comment: Your "synchronous" solution is showing an asynchronous solution (or at least appears as such from what's shown).  So the answer to "what would it do if it was asynchronous" is whatever it's doing now... (unless you're doing something really odd like having synchronous methods return completed tasks)

Comment: I am confused as to why you say your synchronous code has awaits.

Comment: Put the data in a buffer, bro!

Comment: Do you control the API side? If you need data every 200ms, you should really be using SignalR or WebSockets, but there may still be solutions if you are forced to use a WebAPI call.

Comment: Suppose you have an employee who you expect to make a sandwich every five minutes, and it takes them six minutes to make most of the sandwiches. What do you do then? If there was a solution to your programming problem then the same solution would apply to my sandwich making problem.

Comment: @EricLippert I think he means that it usually takes 50ms to get data and 50ms to process it, but sometimes it takes 160ms to get the data, and he wants to know how to deal with that. Like user3093582 said, buffering the reads and processing the data in the background could work.

Comment: @wllmsaccnt: Maybe. The question sounds like "I have twenty pounds of stuff that I need to fit into a sack that holds ten pounds, what do I do?" You get a bigger sack, or less stuff! If the problem is that the processor is *in general* too slow to meet your requirements then there are only two solutions: buy a faster processor, or lower your requirements.  But the original poster has not said anything about the *distribution* of the work items that take too long and how over they are; if it is 0.1% of the time, then buffering is a clear win. If it's 99.9% then it is not.

Comment: It's not clear if the problem is with throughput or with latency. Or, maybe, it's just 'how to deal with feedback loop' in overloaded system

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. wllmsaccnt is correct. Usually things will process under 200ms but there are occassion when it may take longer under peak load. It does sound like buffering is the way to go (I didn't think of it). Point taken about it being distribution of work that matters. I shall need to consider that and analyse some data. I shall do some research on a good way to implement that.

Comment: @servy sorry, perhaps I am ignorant of what await does. (I am still very much learning). My understanding was that await runs an asyncronous method in a sychronous maner.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than using a while loop, you might consider using BackgroundWorker (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

This will invoke your API requests on a separate thread from your application's main thread, which is probably the source of the 'lag' you mentioned, especially if that is your UI thread.  Rather than making a request every 200ms, you can rely on the BackgroundWorker's events (ie RunWorkerCompleted) to perform another request only after the previous one has completed.  (You could of course always include a minimum 200ms delay between requests by checking the elapsed time in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler)

Comment: The OP is already doing the work asynchronously (or so it appears anyway).  And much of the work is IO bound, so this would just be forcing a thread to sit around doing nothing much of the time, and has no benefits over an asynchronous implementation.

Comment: He might be calling the shown method synchronously;  if that's because there is some reason that the caller cannot await this method, it still might be viable.

Comment: If they were synchronously waiting for this asynchronous method to finish then the solution would simply be to *not do that*, not to re-write it into a different paradigm that involves having threads sitting around doing nothing in order to just not synchronously wait on that other solution.

Comment: Fair enough, but hey man, sometimes good enough is good enough